# How to deal with JVM crash when using AKKA cluster sharding

Tags: akka, sharding

I'm practising Akka cluster sharding function.
I started several entities in 3 nodes using sharding function.
But I don't know how could the entities be recovered in other nodes when one node is crashed.

Can someone help me to understand how could I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The sharding functionality is one of the most powerful features I ever seen in open source projects.
I use sharding using akka 2.3.12 version with success over last 2 3 years already.
As a rule is desired to have around 10 shards per node, but my deployment is using 5 nodes and I have 20 shards per node and works just fine.

Has to be understood that the sharding is only a routing logic that gives you location transparency of where an actor managed by sharding functionality is actually instantiated (what node, and what shard).

Now regarding recovery of the actor:
if your actor has state accumulated by the commands sent, that is important for your business then means you have to persist received commands and be able to recover (CQRS & Event Sourcing) from some persistence available to all nodes. For this akka provides http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/java/persistence.html capabilities, this documentation is very well structured and gives you enough information about how this recovery can be achieved. As a persistence source I used akka persistence with C* plugin - details on https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra

Comment: Thank you Vasile for you prompt answer. Yes I know Akka persistence, and I tried the most simple persistent plugin: shared-leveldb, but seems not working. What I did is: Start 3 instances of Akka system, and using sharding function to send request message and then shard and its entities are created, after that I manually killed one instance, so this instance become "UNREACHEABLE", then I started the same instance again, so the node status become "UP" again, but I don't see the Shards and entites recovered in this node, how should I do to recover the shards and entities for restarted node?

Comment: Let s suppose that your actor (the one managed by sharding) persists each received command and you have logic for it in recover method, let s call this actor SMPA (shard managed persisted actor) with persistence id "smpa" and sent EntryEnvelope message X, was set up to reach this actor. when your producer (in akka 1) sends  this mesaage X, using the sharding region actor first time, SMPA is not yet instantiated, when message X is processed by shardig region tries to find this actor, fails so sharding coordinater will inform the region that this actor was  created in i.e. akka 2.

Comment: After you take akka 2 down and your producer sends another message to SMPA the region from akka 1 will not reach last known address of it, and will try to check with coordinator (in akka 1 - the leader node) that now decides to instantiate the SMPA in akka 3, and now persistence comes into place if akka 3 has access of what last instace of SMPA persisted, after recovery your message will reach this new instance. Hopefully not to long text.

Comment: How sharding works, great documentation -http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-sharding.html#How_it_works

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation. So what I understand is that it need to send another message again to trigger this SMPA reinstalled(recover). What I want to have is that the SMPA can be automatically restarted in other node(e.g. Akka3) when JVM crashed, because in my case the SMPA actor is doing streaming calculation, instead of request/response calculation, so I want the SMPA actor to be recovered itself when JVM crashed, and there is no need for the client side to know the backend calculator is crashed and send the same message again to restart it, is this function possible to have?

Comment: Can you please explain the flow, the usecase, to understand better this streamig calculation? Because it may be the case that can be applied other concepts instead of sharding i.e. routers.

Comment: OK, streaming calculation means the SMPA will never stop. In my case, once the SMPA has been started by the sharding coordinator, it will start to subscribe market data, and the calculation is triggered by any update from market and never stop. So what I want to have is when JVM crashed, the SMPA will automatically recovered in other node so the calculation will be continued.

Comment: I would ratter have an actor - R - started on each akka node that subscribe (since from queue each will read) to market data and then sends to shards (based on the routing logic). Is true that actor R instance from akka 1 it may send to shard placed on akka 3, but this gives you fail recovery capabilities. And if you have a lot of shards is not good to have so many subscriptions to some topic.

Comment: Different actors probably have different topic subscription, so it's not realistic to use one actor as a point to subscribe market data. I'm still wondering about how the recovery can be done.